# Rank values in a 2D array

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, ranking, arcpy

Hi basically I want to input a 2D array and then create a new ranked array with the values from lowest to highest.

The array I am using is an elevation raster converted to a numpyarray. This array has a value for elevation. I only want to sort by elevation. Below is how far I got with the code, but it is not generating what I want!

```
import arcpy
import numpy

array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(r"C:\Current\SedMod\SedModv3\TestModel.gdb\Smallprepfin_Clip")

order = array.argsort()
ranks = order.argsort()

print ranks
```

Thanks for any help!

Additional clarification:

I want to sort all the values contained within the array from the highest value to the lowest value but maintain the indices and shape of the array.

i.e the highest value(elevation) would be rank 1 and the lowest rank 100 if there are 100 values!

Comment: Do you want the result to be a 1D array ?

Comment: Additional clarification:

I want to sort all the values contained within the array from the highest value to the lowest value but maintain the indices and shape of the array.

i.e the highest value(elevation) would be rank 1 and the lowest rank 100 if there are 100 values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.76303184,  0.17748702,  0.89365504,  0.07221609],
       [ 0.12267359,  0.56999037,  0.42877407,  0.8875015 ],
       [ 0.38178661,  0.57648393,  0.47056551,  0.03178402],
       [ 0.03606595,  0.93597727,  0.02199706,  0.73906879]])
>>> a.ravel().argsort().argsort().reshape(a.shape)
array([[12,  5, 14,  3],
       [ 4,  9,  7, 13],
       [ 6, 10,  8,  1],
       [ 2, 15,  0, 11]])
```

Not super happy with this, there is likely a better way.

Comment: Additional clarification:

I want to sort all the values contained within the array from the highest value to the lowest value but maintain the indices and shape of the array.

i.e the highest value(elevation) would be rank 1 and the lowest rank 100 if there are 100 values!

Comment: so for your array I would end up with something like: array([[ 14,  13,  15,  7],
       [ 2,  12,  1,  16 ],
       [ 5,  6,  11,  3],
       [4,  9,  8,  10]])

Comment: Hmmm I can't seem to get it to work can you write it in code like this: import arcpy
import numpy

array = ([[ 0.76303184,  0.17748702,  0.89365504,  0.07221609],
       [ 0.12267359,  0.56999037,  0.42877407,  0.8875015 ],
       [ 0.38178661,  0.57648393,  0.47056551,  0.03178402],
       [ 0.03606595,  0.93597727,  0.02199706,  0.73906879]])

sorted_array = numpy.ravel(a).argsort().argsort().reshape(a.shape)

print sorted_array

Comment: >>> a
[[0.76303184, 0.17748702, 0.89365504, 0.07221609], [0.12267359, 0.56999037, 0.42877407, 0.8875015], [0.38178661, 0.57648393, 0.47056551, 0.03178402], [0.03606595, 0.93597727, 0.02199706, 0.73906879]]
>>> a.ravel().argsort().argsort().reshape(a.shape)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Comment: You need to convert the list of list to a numpy array. `array=numpy.array(array)`. On this note I wouldnt name an array `array` perhaps `arr` or some other variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need `scipy.stats.rankdata` for this

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
ranks=rankdata(a).reshape(a.shape)
```

To rank from highest to lowest, invert the input a

```
ranks=rankdata(a.max()-a).reshape(a.shape)
```