# how to make rank array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**Given a numpy ndarray A, return its rank array.**

**Input** : [[ 9 4 15 0 18]
[16 19 8 10 1]]

**Return value**: [[4 2 6 0 8]
[7 9 3 5 1]]

****but I didnt solve actually I solve but my solution is wrong**

**how can I solve ? please help me***emphasized text***

```
import numpy as np
array=np.array([[9,4,15,0,18],[16,19,8,10,1]])


array_1=np.array([9,4,15,0,18])
array_2=np.array([16,19,8,10,1])

temp1 = array_1.argsort()
temp2 = array_2.argsort()

ranks1 = np.arange(len(array_1))[temp1.argsort()]
rankss=ranks1.argsort()
ranks2 = np.arange(len(array_2))[temp2.argsort()]



print(ranks1*array.ndim)
print(rankss)
```

Comment: why are you repeating argsort without any meanning? the result of `np.arange(len(array_1))[temp1.argsort()]` is equal to `temp1.argsort()`

Comment: repeat question check this link out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505049/how-to-construct-a-rank-array-with-numpy-what-is-a-rank-array/65505159#65505159)

Comment: `array.flatten().argsort().argsort().reshape(array.shape)`

Comment: @adirabargil you are right ı make mistake while I write normally it wil not repeat

Comment: @Stef solution is way more easier to implement, and faster for big data...

Answer (score 1):

If you pass *axis=None* to *argsort* then the source array
is flattened at the first step (and only then arg-sorted).

So probably the shortest code is:

```
result = arr.argsort(axis=None).reshape(arr.shape)
```

No need to explicitely flatten the source array and only
a **single** call to *argsort*.