# Find top n values in row of a dataframe (Python)

Tags: python

i want to find the top n values in a row of a dataframe.

Practical example:

```
data = {'First':  [1, 2,3],
        'Second': [2,1,5],
         'Third': [5,1,2]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','Second','Third'])

 First Second Third
0   1   2   5
1   2   1   3
2   3   5   2
```

I want to iterate through each row and select the top n values. In this example the top 2 and replace the values with 1 and all others with 0.

So my desired output would look like:

```
 First Second Third
0   0   1   1
1   1   0   1
2   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `df.rank` with method set to `min` and get the ones that are greater than `a number of columns - 2` which is same as `(df.shape[1]-n)` to get the top 2. Then `astype` to `int` -

```
data = {'First':  [1, 2,3],
        'Second': [2,1,5],
         'Third': [5,3,2]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','Second','Third'])


n = 2 #define top n

(df.rank(1)>(df.shape[1]-n)).astype(int)
```

```
   First  Second  Third
0      0       1      1
1      1       0      1
2      1       1      0
```

**Alternate:** You can use numpy to solve this as well. The double argsort returns a rank order for each number row-wise. The threshold for top n will be one less in this case since ranking starts from 0 instead. -

```
new_data = (df.to_numpy().argsort(1).argsort()>(df.shape[1]-n-1)).astype(int)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['First','Second','Third'])
print(df2)
```

```
   First  Second  Third
0      0       1      1
1      1       0      1
2      1       1      0
```

Comment: Clever, but I don't follow the second `argsort`... Care to elaborate? Also the third row output is incorrect, maybe it just needs a tweak.

Comment: Argsort only returns the position the indices that would sort an array. To turn that into a rankorder, you need to argsort those indices as well. check this for details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505049/how-to-construct-a-rank-array-with-numpy-what-is-a-rank-array/65505379#65505379

Comment: Thanks, but i your first solution doesn't result in a ranking. I'd need something that really ranks all values in  a row. So the top n = 1 else 0

Comment: Updated my answer to work with all ranks. Do check and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function for converting the values to 0 or 1 based on whether they fit in top2 or not.
Then this function can be applied to the dataframe via `apply` method.

```
import pandas as pd


def filter_top_2(row):
    top_2_items = sorted(row, reverse=True)[:2]
    return [
        1
        if x in top_2_items
        else 0
        for x in row
    ]



data = {
    'First':  [1, 2, 3],
    'Second': [2, 1, 5],
    'Third': [5, 1, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print(df.apply(filter_top_2, axis=1, result_type='broadcast'))
```

Output

```
   First  Second  Third
0      1       2      5
1      2       1      1
2      3       5      2
   First  Second  Third
0      0       1      1
1      1       1      1
2      1       1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

```py
out = df.rank(axis=1).lte(2)
```

Decide on which ranking method works for you from the docs.